# Checking MBProgressHUD status if it hide/show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, progress-bar, mbprogresshud

I'm displaying some views,webVies and while they are loading i display an ProgressHud with waiting message. I'm using an instance of that object :

```
MBProgressHUD * progrssHUD
```

Using the `show` and `hide` methods to control over loading windows. In some views i would like to add view only after the `hide` method is turned on - meaning no window displayed now.

How can i check from any interface what is that status of `MBProgressHUD` and only after status X to do something?

Answer (score 3):

If you see the implementation of `MBProgresshud` then you will find that when they are hiding it they are setting it's `alpha` 0 and when they are showing it they are setting it alpha 1.

So you can use this property to check whether it is hidden or shown.
i.e

```
if(progrssHUD.alpha == 0){
  //perform hide operation
}else{
  //Perform show operation
}
```

Comment: But how can i connected to that shared instance? if i use `MBProgressHUB *HUB = [MBProgressHUB  alloc];` and then i check `HUB.alpha`, it's always 0 even when the `progressHub` is in hide.

Comment: i don't understand you. If progressHud is hidden then it's alpha value will be 0 and if it is showing it will give you 1

Comment: yes but i call in from one class and now i want to check it global status(`alpha`) from another class..so if i check with the code above i always getting 0, maybe the problem is that i don't sync to the global instance of that `progressHUD`?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)SHOW{
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
     HUD.delegate = self;
    [HUD show:YES];
    // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(showHUD) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
      }

- (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud {
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    [HUD release];
    HUD = nil;
}
```

THE METHOD showWhileExecuting CALLING THE HUD WAS ACTIVE WHILE THE DELEGATE METHOD WILL COME.